# Match a specific subdomain but any domain using regex

Tags: regex

I want to match a specific subdomain but any domain using regex.

Exemple :

- http://webmail.domain1.com => MATCH
- http://webmail.domain2.net =>  MATCH
- http://webmail.domain3.de => MATCH
- http://www.domain1.com =>   DON'T MATCH
- http://some.domain2.be => DON'T MATCH
- http://another.domain3.com => DON'T MATCH

I also need in that regex match to get a matching group with the rest of the querystring :

http://webmail.domain1.com/default.aspx?q=1&p=2

- Group 1 : http://webmail.domain1.com => this MUST match
- Group 2 : default.aspx?q=1&p=2

Comment: What have you got so far? If you just need http ://webmail at the beginning, this should work : `^http:\/\/webmail\.`

Comment: Hum, i've to update my question, since i need to match in a group what is after the hostname http://webmail.domain1.com/(i need what ever is there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(http:\/\/webmail\..+?\.com)(.*)
```

Test here: http://rubular.com/r/rVu8zYHCE7

Here is one that isn't specific to `.com`:

```
^(http:\/\/webmail\..+?(?:\/|$))(.*)
```

Comment: I also need to match any LTD : .com, .net or any other. Not specific to .com

Comment: why have you escaped the forward slashes? (that's a rhetorical question... you don't need to)

Comment: I have escaped them because rubular requires you to. It's true, you don't really need to. Unless you're using it as a pattern delimiter (eg. in javascript) @Bohemian.